# Custom filter pipe in Angular doesn't return the right results

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, filtering

I have a use case where I want to be able to search through a list of users that are registered in a mongodb in my Angular application.

For this purpose I'm filtering the users based on their address using custom pipes. However, it never returns the correct user. If I type the letter "W" in the search field and the application finds 2 addresses where the instance 'W' occurs, it will just return the 2 first registered users in the database, not the users who actually lives at an address that has a 'W' included in it. If there's 3 instances, it will return the 3 first users in the database and so on..

I'm thinking that this must be because of the fact that I'm showing each user in the database based on an index, but I don't know how I could show a user list otherwise.

This is the code:

**filter.pipe.ts:**

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
  import { User } from "../entities/user";

 @Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
  })
 @Injectable()
   export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

//ARGS contain what we write in the field.
transform(items: User[], args: string): any {

if(args && items.length > 0) {
    let itemsFound = items.filter(

        item => 
        item.address && 
        item.address.toLowerCase().includes(args.toLowerCase())


    );


    if(itemsFound && itemsFound.length > 0) {


        return itemsFound;
    }

    return [-1]; //in case none is found.
}

return items; // we could change to return [] if we didnt want to show any users until someone wrote something in
} }
```

**user-list.component.html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

  <div *ngFor="let user of users | filter: search; let i = index" class="e2e-baby">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-12 mt-4">     
   <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title><b>Babys navn:</b> {{users[i].fullnameBaby}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle><b>Forældrens navn: </b> {{users[i].fullname}}  </mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>



      <img  mat-card-image src="http://localhost:3000/{{users[i].profilePicture}}" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu" style="width:400px; height: 350px;">

      <mat-card-content>
        <p>
        {{users[i].infoAboutUser}}
        </p>

        <p><small>Kan findes her: {{users[i].address}}, {{users[i].zipcode}} </small></p>
      </mat-card-content>



      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="hire(users[i])">Hyr</button>
        <button mat-button>Rate</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>


  </div> 
  <!-- end of colcard -->



    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**user-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { IAppState } from '../store/store';
import {changeNavbarColor} from '../../assets/javascript/transperentNavbar.js';
import { UsersService } from '../users.service';
import { UsersActions } from '../users.actions';
import { Sitter } from '../entities/sitter';
import { User } from '../entities/user';

import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss'],

})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  private users: User[];

  constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>, private userService: UsersService,
  private usersActions :UsersActions) { changeNavbarColor(); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersActions.getUsers(); //gets all users on the load of the page

    this.ngRedux.select(state => state.users).subscribe(u=> {
      this.users = u.users;
      console.log(this.users);

    })

  }


  hire(user: User){

    this.userService.sendNotification(user).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
    console.log("This guy have been hired.")
    console.log(user);
  }
}
```

Anyone who has an idea of how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Try using `.indexOf()` on `item.address` instead of `.includes()`. Unless I'm mistaken, `.includes()` works on arrays, not strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using indexOf(), but when doing so it doesn't filter anything at all

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Have you made sure everything is declared correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this solution

I have create a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-filter-pipe-in-angular-doesnt-return-the-right-results?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

> HTML Code

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="terms" placeholder="Serach any fields"/>

<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Venue</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let usrData of users | search:terms">
    <td>{{usrData.name}}</td>
    <td>{{usrData.venue}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Ts File code

```
 users=[{
    name:'test 1',
    venue:'venue 1'
  },{
    name:'user',
    venue:'305 vijay nagar'
  },{
    name:'Admin',
    venue:'test venue'
  },{
    name:'user 5',
    venue:'254561'
  }]
```

> Search filter

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!args){
      return value;
    }
    return value.filter((val)=>{
      let rVal=(val.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(args)) || (val.venue.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(args));
      return rVal;
    })

  }

}
```

Comment: This solved my question, because after analysing your answer I found out that instead of viewing users using {{users[i].address}} and having it index based I could just write {{user.address}}. When i did so my filtering worked. Thanks a lot for taking the time to write this! Helped a ton.